# How to understand shallow size and retain size in a Tree or Trie?

Tags: java, kotlin, memory, profiling

I have a character trie data structure which looks like this:

```
sealed class TrieNode(val children: MutableMap<Char, TrieNode>) {
    class NormalNode(kids: MutableMap<Char, TrieNode>) : TrieNode(kids)
    class EndNode(kids: MutableMap<Char, TrieNode>, val info: SubInfo) : TrieNode(kids)
}
```

As you can see my trie consists of `NormalNode` and `EndNode`, where `NormalNode`s are the internal nodes and `EndNode`s are the leaf once.

When I did the memory profiling after creating the trie in runtime, I could see that the shallow memory usage for the class TrieNode is `1 MB` while retention usage is `120 MB`. The code is run in android and the implementation doesn't seem to have any bugs.

My question is whether the retention memory of a class makes sense in this kind of nested/composite implementation. Shallow size is the size of the object itself. But retained size is the total size of all private references(references only accessed through this path) and its children references. Now consider a tree/trie made of the same kind of objects. The shallow size of each node will be the size of the node, but retain size will be the size of the node + sum of the sizes of all its children because all its children can only be accessed through this one parent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I don't think there's a single definitive answer to this, but here are some thoughts.)

As you say, the ‘shallow’ size should include only the `TrieNode` objects themselves, and not anything they refer to.  And the ‘retain’ size will normally include anything that's reachable *from* those classes: that will include their `children` maps and all the rest of the trie reachable from them; also the `info` objects they refer to (and anything *they* refer to…).

My immediate concern is the use of a `Map` object for each node, because most `Map` implementations take quite a bit of memory — and you'll be creating one for each node of your trie.

The most common type of map is a hash map, which holds an array for the hash table (which might start with 16 or more entries, and will grow as needed to be significantly larger than the number of entries); depending how it's implemented, each non-empty hash entry might point to a linked list of nodes, each of which might have references to the key and corresponding value.  That's a fair few objects, taking more memory than you might expect.  (`ConcurrentHashMap` gets good concurrent performance at the cost of using even more memory.)

So I suspect that that will account for a lot of the difference between shallow and deep memory usages.  (Of course, the `info` objects in your trie will be included in that, too, so if those are very big or end up referring to lots of stuff, then the maps might not be the major factor.)

So if memory usage is a real issue, you might want to reconsider rewriting your class to use a different form of storage.  (That could take a lot of effort, and make it more complex and/or much less general, so only worth doing if it's a significant problem.)

For example, if you expected each node to have a very small number of children, then you could replace the Map with parallel arrays of keys and values — most operations would then be O(n), but if n is always small then that could be outweighed by the memory saving.  And/or if you knew that your keys were always `Char`s, say, then you could hard-code that type and avoid all the boxed primitives.

(As a half-way house, you create a new `MutableMap` implementation with some of the memory benefits; you could then keep your nice clean trie implementation.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but are we sure that retention memory value shown in the profiler  double-counted ?

Comment: Oh no, any reasonable profiler won't _double_-count anything.  The main area of uncertainty is whether it counts anything with _other_ references, and so would have to remain in memory after your trie was removed.  But that may not be happening here; as mentioned, once you count all the maps and _their_ internal objects, as well as your `info` objects, I wouldn't be at all surprised to find all that taking a couple of orders of magnitude more space than your simple little `TrieNode` classes themselves (which contain only one or two object references each).